# How can I change the language of FlareGet to English?

Tags: language-support, flareget

I installed FlareGet from the Ubuntu Software Center, but found that the language is not English. It is in Spanish or French or something, I don't know.

How can I change the language of FlareGet to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/default/locale`
2. Make file looks like this:

   ```
   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
   LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
   ```
3. Run `sudo locale-gen`.
4. Log-out and log-in again

Comment: Won't this be global?

Comment: Yes, it will. In this case QT application ignores `$LANG` and reads `$LC_NUMERIC` or `$LC_ALL`. To set locale only for one user lines like `export LANG=en_AU.UTF-8` should be added to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: There is a GUI for handling language and locales settings (Language Support), but if you set LC_ALL permanently, you in effect disable Language Support. **LC_ALL should never be set in `/etc/default/locale`.** In addition, setting LANG in `~/.bashrc` is also bad advice, since Language Support stores its user level settings in `~/.pam_environment` and `~/.bashrc` would override PAM.

Answer (score 1):

please download flareget from its website:

http://flareget.com

The version in Ubuntu Software Center is old, and even doesn't support browser integration.

If you still face the language problem, then click this icon:
[image]
Then click the following icon:
[image]

then click the combo box:
[image]